# Remove all saved networks Android Things1.0

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Is it posible to remove all kind of saved networks in Android Things 1.0?
I cannot remove one, I get this message:
*WifiConfigManager: UID 10034 does not have permission to delete configuration "someNetName"*

In documentation i only saw that user cannot delete saved Newtorks not created by him.

I use WifiManager class:

```
   public void removeProfiles() {
        List<WifiConfiguration> list = mWifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

        for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
            mWifiManager.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
        }
    }
```